# Media player doesnt work anymore on api level 29

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

ive been using the simple examples of mediaplayer streaming from a http server hosting a mp3 file

and it works flawlessly ( that is on api level 23 ) , when i try the same code on api level 29

it no longer works and gives the following error code:

```
2020-05-06 04:02:47.899 6926-6953/com.example.alarmmanager E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
2020-05-06 04:02:47.900 6926-6926/com.example.alarmmanager E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

ive been looking everywhere for the meaning of the error code or how to make this work on api level 29 and above
my code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
    final Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaplayerhandler("start");
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaplayerhandler("pause");
        }
    });
}
public void mediaplayerhandler(String status){
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    String url = "http://server.com/song.mp3"; // your URL here
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(status.equals("pause")){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
    else if(status.equals("start")){
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60863792/8956604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if, cleartext http traffic support is disabled. 
It is disabled by default in Android 28 and greater.

See this [link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-network-security-config/index.html#3)